# Cannot make sense of this error (ERROR: endpoints do not enclose a minimum (gsl: fsolver.c:126))

Tags: c++, fft, physics

I'm working with this code: https://github.com/UCLA-TMD/Ogata. If performs a fast fourier transform.

It integrates the function *test*, according to some predefined options that are argument of the FBT  - FBT(bessel order,some option that doesnt matter,Number of function calls, estimate value where function has its maximum). So far so good.

This code works fine with that function from *test*, but that's not the function I actually need to use, so I switched to something like exp(x) just to test it, and I no matter what I do I always get:

(It always compiles okay, but when I run the .o file, it gives me this)

**gsl: fsolver.c:126: ERROR: endpoints do not enclose a minimum
Default GSL error handler invoked.
Aborted (core dumped)**

At first I thought it could be a problem with the function's maximum value Q in FBT, but whenever I change it, it gives me the same error.

Would really appreciate any help.

```
double test( double x, double width ){ return x*exp(-x/width);} // test function to transform data allows to send anything else to the function


int main( void )
{

 //FBT(Bessel Order nu, option of function (always zero), number of function calls,  rough estimate where the maximum of the function f(x) is).
 
  FBT ogata0 = FBT(0.0,0,10,1.0); // Fourier Transform with Jnu, nu=0.0 and N=10
  
  double qT = 1.;
  double width = 1.;

 //call da ogata 0 para função teste 
  auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  double res = ogata0.fbt(std::bind(test, std::placeholders::_1, width),qT);
  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


  std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << " FT( J0(x*qT) x*exp(-x) ) at qT= " << qT << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << "Numerical transformed = " << res << std::endl;
  auto overhead=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-begin).count();
  std::cout<<"Calc time: "<<overhead<<" nanoseconds\n";



}
```

Comment: Depending on the version of GSL you are running you may want to look at this bug [gsl: fsolver.c:126: ERROR: endpoints do not enclose a minimum](https://github.com/zhanxw/rvtests/issues/32) -- that was fixed about 5 years ago, but some distros may be running GSL builds from about that time. Also see: [unselected answer in - Is this a bug in GSL's minimum finding routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18807512/3422102) for explanation of why that error can occur.